# How can I get the values from wolfram wlexpr when I use python to solve equations?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr, Global

wlpath = '/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.2/Executables/MathKernel'

sess = WolframLanguageSession(wlpath)

exp = wlexpr('''
            Slove[GegenbauerC[11, 1.0, x]==0, x]
            ''')
sess.evaluate(exp)
x=sess.evaluate(x)
# sess.terminate()
print(x)

sess.terminate()
```

I can't get the x solved from equation.
How can I do it ?

I tried to use

```
xs = sess.evaluate(Global.x) ;
print(xs);
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe the [SciPy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gegenbauer.html) can meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs a minor restructuring:

1. The `Slove` inside `wlexpr()` is a typo. Replace it to `Solve`.
2. You aren't storing the output of `sess.evaluate(exp)`. You need to store that output like `x = sess.evaluate(exp)`
3. Remove `x=sess.evaluate(x)` as it will evaluate another function named `x` (which I don't think is defined in your case).

After this, you can terminate your session, and then print the value of x.

Here's the modified code:

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr, Global

wlpath = '/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.2/Executables/MathKernel'

sess = WolframLanguageSession(wlpath)

exp = wlexpr('''
            Solve[GegenbauerC[11, 1.0, x]==0, x]
            ''')
x = sess.evaluate(exp)
sess.terminate()

print(x)
```